# coredumpctl: command not found in ubuntu 14.04.5

Tags: ubuntu, coredump

When I try to run coredumpctl from ubuntu 14.04.5, it complained "coredumpctl: command not found". 
Anything I have to do to make the cmd available? Please kindly help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming. Consider https://askubuntu.com/ instead

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 14.04 Does not have the `coredumpctl` utility available, as it does not use SystemD.

However, in later version of ubuntu you could have used the `apt search` command to find packages:

```
$ apt search coredumpctl
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
systemd-coredump/zesty-updates,zesty-security 232-21ubuntu7.1 amd64
  tools for storing and retrieving coredumps
```

As you can see, the package is called `systemd-coredump` use `apt install packagename` to install it.

Comment: In my client (Ubuntu 14.04.5), I can't anything by "apt search coredumpctl".

Comment: 14.04 does not have this command available yet, as it does not use Systemd.